# Accessing string representations of constant field values in java

Tags: java, field, constants

I am using an imported class with has constant field values set using:

```
public static final int BLUE = 1;
public static final int GREEN = 2;
```

etc.

Is there any way of getting a string representation of the constant field value from the int value?

i.e. given the value 2 I want to get a string of GREEN.

P.S. This isn't my class so I can't use ENUMs

Comment: You mean `BLUE = 1` etc. Then use `Foo.BLUE` where `Foo` is the name of the class.

Comment: 1 or 2 can't be names of variables

Comment: have a look at enum, use ordinal. May be that will help.

Comment: Use Enums http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: use any <key,value> pair container, so you can get both key and if needed value too.

Comment: You really don't, since that wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* you can change the class which contains these constants, it would be better to make it an enum with a `value()` method.

Otherwise, I would suggest building a `Map<Integer, String>` *once* using reflection, and then just doing map lookups:

```
Map<Integer, String> valueToStringMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Field field : Foo.class.getFields()) {
    int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
    if (field.getType() == Integer.class && Modifier.isPublic(modifiers)
        && Modifier.isStatic(modifiers)) {
        valueToStringMap.put((Integer) field.get(null), field.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried this I didn't get what I was wanted so reposting.

Comment: @Michael_user3015308: "I didn't get what I was wanted" gives us almost no information - in what *way* did it not do what you wanted? Did it not find all the fields? Additionally, posting a new question which is effectively a duplicate of an existing one is frowned on... especially when the new question has no more information than this one, really.

Answer (score 1):

I think your friend here would be enums

```
public enum Color {
  BLUE(1), GREEN(2);
}
```

Now if you try to get `Color.BLUE.ordinalValue()` it will return `1` and if you say `Color.BLUE.name()` it will return `BLUE`.

You can also declare private variables in the enum just like a pojo class and initialize them un the constructor. You can write getter methods to return those variables.