# String values of field constants in java

Tags: java

Is there any way of getting a string representation of the constant field value from the int value?

For example  java.util.Calendar declares several field values such as
`public final static int AUGUST = 7;`

It there any way to get this information into a `Map<Integer, String> containing for instance`
<7,"AUGUST">`, etc.

P.S. This isn't my class so I can't use ENUMs.  And I'm showing Calendar as an example.

Comment: You would have to use Reflection on the class.

Comment: what you need exactly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing string representations of constant field values in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219181/accessing-string-representations-of-constant-field-values-in-java)

Comment: In what way is this question different from the one you asked earlier today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection. For instance say `Foo` is the class, you can get the fields by using:

```
Foo.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

You can then iterate over the several fields and use `Field.getName()` and `Field.get(null)` to achieve the value.

For instance, say `Foo` has the following definition:

```
public class Foo {

    public static final int JANUARY = 1;
    public static final int FEBRUARY = 2;

}
```

You can run the following code:

```
 HashMap<Object,String> map = new HashMap<>();

 for (Field f : Foo.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
     try {
     int modifiers = field.getModifiers();//check if the field is public and static
     if (Modifier.isPublic(modifiers) && Modifier.isStatic(modifiers)) {
         if (f.get(null) != null) {
             map.put(f.get(null),f.getName());
         }
     } catch (Throwable t) {
     }
 }
```

This will result in a `HashMap` containing `<1,"JANUARY">` and `<2,"FEBRUARY">`.

Comment: This is the inverse of what the OP asked for - a `Map<Integer, String>`. It's easy enough to fix though. I wouldn't recommend catching `Throwable`, mind you...

Comment: I will modify my post. As far as I know there is however not a way to check if a field has static access in advance... Do you have any suggestions on that part?

Comment: Yes - you use getModifiers. See my answer to the OP's nearly-identical question earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219181/accessing-string-representations-of-constant-field-values-in-java

Comment: Just wondering if you can't get theoretical exceptions resulting from the invocation (like `NoSuchField` and `IllegalAccess`). In that case I think it is still useful to catch these exceptions in the loop since failing to obtain one field won't abort the attempts to obtain the values of other fields.

Comment: I would use `getModifiers` to make sure that shouldn't happen - and if it *does* happen, I'd want to turn it into a `RuntimeException` (because my world view is wrong at that point) rather than just continuing regardless.

Answer (score 1):

There *IS* a `Reflection` based solution to this, but I feel that you should avoid `Reflection` where possible. One option is to take the good ol' manual approach..

```
Map<Integer, String> values = HashMap<Integer, String>();

values.put(1, "JANUARY");

// You get the idea.
```

Yes, this isn't as cool, but it gets the job done without calls to `Reflection`, and given that you appear to be a beginner programmer, I would avoid `Reflection` until you're completely, 100% confident.

Comment: I don't see the problem with using reflection as I am only *reading* the field values, not modifying it.

Comment: It's not that you're modifying it; it's that it is hugely inefficient. If you can achieve something without `Reflection`, then you should.

Answer (score -1):

While technically this is possible, with reflection and by using `Class#getDeclaredFields()`, the fact that you asked this is enough of an indication that you should not use it.

Comment: -1:  "the fact that you asked this is enough of an indication that you should not use it".  There are plenty of good reasons to avoid reflection, but unfamiliarity with it is not one of them.  Everyone has to start somewhere!

Comment: @KevinK Unfamiliarity alone would not be a reason, of course - and I did not say something like this. But only mentioning that this *can* be solved with reflection (without any word of warning) will cause the asker do this, regardless of whether it is the appropriate solution for his case (and we both know that it is almost certainly *not* appropriate!). When someone wants to shoot himself in the foot, you can give him a gun, but maybe there are also other ways of *helping* someone. I should have elaborated my answer more - that's certainly true - so the downvote may be justified nevertheless